# How do companies change their cryptographic keys?

Tags: encryption, https, cryptography, rsa, encryption-asymmetric

I've done some reading on asymmetric encryption and I asked myself,

key pairs (one's public and private keys) must be replaced at some point - how does it happen?

A company such as facebook can't risk someone managing to crack their private key (even if it would take several years to do it), so they must come up with a new pair once in a while.

My question is how they make clients stop using the old public key and start using the new one.

Thank you.

Comment: What clients? Are you referring to HTTPS?

Comment: Yes, how does my computer know to use the new public key?

Comment: The client does not persist the public key but rather acquires via a certificate every time a connection is made to the TLS server. Thus, the client is not even aware the key changed because it keeps no memory of previous connections.